# Models not recognized in namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, umbraco, umbraco7

Heey all,

I'm working on a Umbraco website. I try to reach my renderModels from my controller but, it says to me that type or namespace could not be found. So i try to add using namespace.Models;.

When i do this the namespace.controllers is reachable but when i try namespace.Models; it gives me the error the type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace.

The folder Models does exist.

I tried searching online for it but could not find a awnser. Pls help

**Edit 1**

*Model*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.Models;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class HomeRenderModel : BaseRenderModel
    {
        public HomeRenderModel()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
    }
}
```

*Controller*

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Models;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;
using MyNamespace.Models;

namespace MyNamespace.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : RenderMvcController
    {
        public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
        {
            var rendermodel = new HomeRenderModel(model.Content, model.CurrentCulture);

            return CurrentTemplate(rendermodel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check what namespace is declared in the model class which you want to use.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that. I'm kinda new, sorry

Comment: There should be a namespace declaration in the model class. You need to check that.  Can you share the entire file content of the model class ?

Comment: So in the controller the using MyNamespace.Models; is not working

Comment: Can you share the code of `HomeRenderModel.cs` file?

Comment: Its the top code

Comment: For starters, qualify your **MODEL** namespace references to be sure they aren't clashing. For example **using uModels = Umbraco.Web.Models;** and **using myModels = MyNamespace.Models;**

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, but basically I did the tutorial that mentions the model and controller etc. out there and had the same problem. I figured out that I had created the model folder containing the classes in the wrong place. You may have the same simple problem here.

Minimize all your folders in the project explorer, and then expand to see where you placed them. Your sub folders need to be in the project (in the 'folder' with the little globe icon, not above it with the solution properties.)